# FileReader - readAsText encoding both utf-8 and ANSI

Tags: javascript, utf-8, readfile

I'm using the API readAsText for getting the content from file with french characters

```
encoding = "UTF-8"
reader.readAsText(e.target.files.item(0), encoding)
```

The files could be encoding by UTF-8 or ANSI, in this case it is not working for ANSI file while reading UTF-8 and also not working for UTF-8 file while reading ANSI file.

I've tried `ISO-8859-1`, `ISO-8859-3`, `ISO-8859-4`, `CP1251`, `latin1`, none of them work for both.

So is there a way to read both utf-8 and ANSI, or whith encoding I should use for french file ? thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I also meet the problem.in the end, I tried encode type twice，first get utf-8 response,check if it is right,otherwise encode with ansi again.Hope can help you!

Comment: please give an code example to make it clear what you mean.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).